# How to Implement Asynchtask on a CollectionView(Listview,gridview) in Android ?

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

Hello Dear Android Fellows,
I am working on an application which have a gridview which performs something like running progress bar on every individual item. i am using Asynchtask on thread pool to update progress bar. it is updating every single item's progress bar fine but it creates a Problem for me. 
The Problem is that when i scroll gridview it creates out of memory problem as getview recycles and creates new threads. Please help me how i should tackle this **Out Of Memory Problem** and tell me where i should destroy old threads. Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

You can set thread pool size to avoid out of memory,

in-case if you are loading images, you try this library

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader